# Postgres subquery has access to column in a higher level table. Is this a bug? or a feature I don't understand?

Tags: postgresql

I don't understand why the following doesn't fail. How does the subquery have access to a column from a different table at the higher level?

```
drop table if exists temp_a;
create temp table temp_a as
(
    select 1 as col_a
);

drop table if exists temp_b;
create temp table temp_b as
(
    select 2 as col_b
);

select col_a from temp_a where col_a in (select col_a from temp_b); 
/*why doesn't this fail?*/
```

The following fail, as I would expect them to.

```
select col_a from temp_b; 
/*ERROR:  column "col_a" does not exist*/

select * from temp_a cross join (select col_a from temp_b) as sq;   
/*ERROR:  column "col_a" does not exist 
 *HINT:  There is a column named "col_a" in table "temp_a", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.*/
```

I know about the LATERAL keyword ([link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL), [link](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.3#LATERAL_JOIN)) but I'm not using LATERAL here. Also, this query succeeds even in pre-9.3 versions of Postgres (when the LATERAL keyword was introduced.)

Here's a sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/09f62/5/0

Thank you for any insights.

Comment: This is a "feature". The visibility rules of identifiers in sub-selects are defined by the SQL standard, and this is what the standard requires. The inner select has access to all columns of the outer select: http://postgresql.nabble.com/Is-this-a-bug-or-a-feature-Column-visibility-in-subquery-from-outer-query-td1917332.html

Comment: It may be part of the SQL standard, but it is very confusing.

Comment: It is confusing. And the meaning of the query can silently change if that column ever gets added to second table, no warnings about ambiguous columns or anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although this feature might be confusing, without it, several types of queries would be more difficult, slower, or impossible to write in sql. This feature is called a "correlated subquery" and the correlation can serve a similar function as a join.

For example: Consider this statement

```
select first_name, last_name from users u
where exists (select * from orders o where o.user_id=u.user_id)
```

Now this query will get the names of all the users who have ever placed an order. Now, I know, you can get that info using a join to the orders table, but you'd also have to use a "distinct", which would internally require a sort and would likely perform a tad worse than this query. You could also produce a similar query with a group by.

Here's a better example that's pretty practical, and not just for performance reasons. Suppose you want to delete all users who have no orders and no tickets.

```
delete from users u where 
not exists (select * from orders o where o.user_d = u.user_id)
and not exists (select * from tickets t where t.user_id=u.ticket_id)
```

One very important thing to note is that you should fully qualify or alias your table names when doing this or you might wind up with a typo that completely messes up the query and silently "just works" while returning bad data.

The following is an example of what NOT to do.

```
select * from users
where exists (select * from product where last_updated_by=user_id)
```

This looks just fine until you look at the tables and realize that the table "product" has no "last_updated_by" field and the user table does, which returns the wrong data. Add the alias and the query will fail because no "last_updated_by" column exists in product.

I hope this has given you some examples that show you how to use this feature. I use them all the time in update and delete statements (as well as in selects-- but I find an absolute need for them in updates and deletes often)